# Bug in JSON parsing of SageMaker endpoint?

Tags: json, amazon-sagemaker

I am using a TF model that is deployed in SageMaker to make predictions.
The input for prediction is an array of Strings.
E.g. I can call it successfully with:

```
input = {
  'instances': ["Hello world"]
}
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowPredictor
predictor = TensorFlowPredictor('endpoint-name', sagemaker_session)
predictor.predict(input)
```

However, if a String in the String array includes '][' I get an error message about the validity of the Json array

```
input = {
  'instances': ["]["]
}
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowPredictor
predictor = TensorFlowPredictor('endpoint-name', sagemaker_session)
predictor.predict(input)
```

The error message is:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with message "{ "error": "JSON Value: {\n    \"instances\": {\n        \"instances\": [\n            \"][\"\n        ]\n    }\n} Excepting 'instances' to be an list/array" }". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/endpoint-name in account XXXXXXXXX for more information.
```

As far as I can tell the JSON I'm sending

```
{
  'instances': ["Hello world"]
}
```

is a valid JSON (I also checked it with some online json viewers that accept it as legal JSON).
Is this some bug in SageMaker's JSON parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Printing the error message with the newlines makes it a bit more readable:

```
JSON Value: {
    "instances": {
        "instances": [
            "]["
        ]
    }
} Excepting 'instances' to be an list/array
```

With that spacing, we can see that the first "instances" value is not a list but rather another dictionary with "instances" as its key.

Does it work if you change your prediction input to a list? i.e.

```py
input = ["]["]
predictor.predict(input)
```

Comment: The prediction input should be a JSON with a field named 'instances' (as in the example I posted above). It does look like a bug on SageMaker's side, as the error it gives shows the JSON with an added 'instances' dictionary, which was not in the input.

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that `prediction.predict` is adding the "instances" dictionary. What happens if you don't include the dictionary as part of `input`?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same thing, but then in batch prediction. I have a application/jsonlines file format, with an instance on each line. I am performing text classification. All seems to work great for me as long as I don't have a "][" inside my features. It seems to me like a SageMaker problem as well. I think that I will try to solve this problem by replacing [->( and ]->) for now. Or do you have a better solution?